# Set height of children in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use RecyclerView in a similar way to ViewPager (Vertical).

I have setup fling and scroll gestures so the views are scrolled in exactly the same way as ViewPager but now I would like to setup children views (LinearLayoutManager) and LinearLayout used for each child view to fill screen instead of wrap_content. I have made all views to match_parent and fill_parent but that does not work.

I did this:

holder.layout.setMinimumHeight(this.recyclerView.getMeasuredHeight());

Which is nice but when the orientation changes then layout overflows the screen which makes smooth scrolling/gestures flicker etc. I don't want it to overflow the screen.

Any good tips how to make it properly so all children are laid out to maximum height of the screen but do not overflow?

Thanks

Edit: I changed setting minimum height to this:

holder.layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, this.recyclerView.getHeight()));

which solves flickering issue but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I have low reputation so unable to comment down. thats why answering here .

to over come the overflow issue lets say you have XMl of single item like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="horizontal" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout" >

<-- some views --->>

</RelativeLayout>
```

now in your adapter get this Layout in viewHolder

and make a boolean variable where you are setting adabpter.. which you can use for knowing orientation changed . when orientation get changed then change its value .

in your adapter make a function 
    public void orientaiotnChange(){
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

in your function

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int arg1) {
if(isOrientationHorizontal){
 viewHolder.Mainlayout.setOrientation(horizontal);
 }
else{
 viewHolder.Mainlayout.setOrientation(vertical);
}
```

also change the orientation of RecyclerView in activity from where you set adapter and from where you are checking orientation is changed or not .

hopefully it will work so :)